# Minecraft Launcher not listing v1.14 in versions dropdown

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

So on my kid's Windows machine, the Minecraft launcher's version dropdown list does not include v1.14.  It only lists up to v1.12.2.

What do we need to do to get it to list v1.14?

Comment: Connect to the internet maybe? Or there's some firewall issue.

Comment: The machine is definitely connected to the internet, and the problem persists even with the Windows Firewall Off.

Comment: Maybe it's not the only firewall. Routers can have them, even some internet providers have general firewalls for everyone. The only way I know to be completely sure that it's not that is to run a VM on that computer and try it in there.

Answer (score 1):

On the new launcher, the first page will list by default the newest version. Anyways, you might have changed that setting.

There’s an option where you can choose which versions to display on launcher’s version selector.
You can watch [this video](https://youtu.be/wvR8A3qR2qQ) that explains how to do that (the guy open the launcher at 1:30).